# White List and Black List for SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, openssh

How to create a (username/password or certificate) white/black list for ssh?

For example of blacklist, I can use any username/password combination to access the server, except the ones on the blacklist.

The ssh version can be OpenSSH.

And the server is a Linux.

Creating lots of users on Linux for white list is not a nice way.

Any approach can be used, like modifying SSH software itself, or using Linux/SSH features, or using other modules.

---

Update:

Maybe I did not describe the situation clearly.
Basically, I simply want any username/password combination to be able to login, except the black list.

For example, if the black list is "admin/admin; root/123".
I can simply use "abc/123456" to login.
The server is like a VERY VULNERABLE one with almost no credential needed.

For white list, I can give a number of username/password/certificate combinations for the list, not just the username.

Comment: Using a blacklist of "admin/admin;root/123", what is the expected behavior if a user attempts login with "root/456"?  Since that specific combination is NOT in the blacklist, should that be acceptable to login as root?

Comment: Play with the PAM stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a blacklist, in your `sshd_config` add the `DenyUsers` entry followed by a list of users separated by a space.  You can also use `DenyGroups` in a similar fashion.

For example:
`DenyUsers jimmy bill joe susan`

or

`DenyGroups teachers`

A whitelist is created by using the `AllowUsers` and/or `AllowGroups` entries in the `sshd_config` file.  If either of these entries is used, only those users or groups listed will be permitted to login.

Comment: Please see the update. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: for me I had to use the name as appears in the terminal for this method to work e.g. `DenyUsers root@the-host`